# JavaScript - Loop through all object property and make new array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this data **:**

```
let obj = {
    "additional_image_link": [
        [
            "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@2.jpg",
            "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@2F.jpg",
        ]
    ],
    "aff_link": "https://go.linkwi.se/z/11593-0/CD24352/?lnkurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.celestino.gr%2Fel-GR%2Fpanteloni-me-pietes-lefko%2Fprd%2FSK7732.1825%2F7%3Faffiliate%3Dlinkwise%26utm_source%3Dlinkwise%26utm_medium%3Dlw%26utm_campaign%3Dlw",
    "all_sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L"
    ],
    "availability": "Y",
    "brand": "Celestino",
    "breadcrumbs": [
        "ΡΟΥΧΑ",
        "ΠΑΝΤΕΛΟΝΙΑ"
    ],
    "breadcrumbs_url": [
        "/el-gr/gynaikeia-rouxa/r=0000000006",
        "/el-gr/gynaikeia-pantelonia/r=0101000000",
        "/el-gr/pantelonia/r=0101001800"
    ],
    "description": "Παντελόνι με πιέτες, κλείσιμο με φερμουάρ και κουμπί, θηλιές στη μέση, με τσέπες, λευκο",
    "id": "SK7732.1825+1",
    "image_link": "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@1F.JPG",
    "link": "https://www.celestino.gr/el-GR/panteloni-me-pietes-lefko/prd/SK7732.1825/7?affiliate=linkwise&utm_source=linkwise&utm_medium=lw&utm_campaign=lw",
    "sizes_in_stock": [
        "S",
        "M"
    ],
    "sizes_in_stock_feed": "S,M,L",
};
```

Now, I want to loop through all the `property` of this object and make a new array of object. I mean `property` will be same but if the property value has array or array of array I want to make it a single array.

What I tried **:**

```
let additional = [];
        
for( property in obj ) {
    if( Array.isArray( obj[ property ] ) ) {
        additional.push({
            [property] : obj[property]
        });
    } else if ( isValidUrl ( obj[ property ] ) ) {
         additional.push({
            [property] : '<a href="' + obj[ property ] + '">' + obj[ property ] + '</a>'
        });
    } else {
         additional.push({
            [property] : obj[property]
        });
    }
}

console.log(additional)
```

The output is **:**

```
[ { additional_image_link: [ [Array] ] },
  { aff_link:
     '<a href="https://go.linkwi.se/z/11593-0/CD24352/?lnkurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.celestino.gr%2Fel-GR%2Fpanteloni-me-pietes-lefko%2Fprd%2FSK7732.1825%2F7%3Faffiliate%3Dlinkwise%26utm_source%3Dlinkwise%26utm_medium%3Dlw%26utm_campaign%3Dlw">https://go.linkwi.se/z/11593-0/CD24352/?lnkurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.celestino.gr%2Fel-GR%2Fpanteloni-me-pietes-lefko%2Fprd%2FSK7732.1825%2F7%3Faffiliate%3Dlinkwise%26utm_source%3Dlinkwise%26utm_medium%3Dlw%26utm_campaign%3Dlw</a>' },
  { all_sizes: [ 'S', 'M', 'L' ] },
  { availability: 'Y' },
  { brand: 'Celestino' },
  { breadcrumbs: [ 'ΡΟΥΧΑ', 'ΠΑΝΤΕΛΟΝΙΑ' ] },
  { breadcrumbs_url:
     [ '/el-gr/gynaikeia-rouxa/r=0000000006',
       '/el-gr/gynaikeia-pantelonia/r=0101000000',
       '/el-gr/pantelonia/r=0101001800' ] },
  { description:
     'Παντελόνι με πιέτες, κλείσιμο με φερμουάρ και κουμπί, θηλιές στη μέση, με τσέπες, λευκο' },
  { id: 'SK7732.1825+1' },
  { image_link: 'https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@1F.JPG' },
  { link:
     '<a href="https://www.celestino.gr/el-GR/panteloni-me-pietes-lefko/prd/SK7732.1825/7?affiliate=linkwise&utm_source=linkwise&utm_medium=lw&utm_campaign=lw">https://www.celestino.gr/el-GR/panteloni-me-pietes-lefko/prd/SK7732.1825/7?affiliate=linkwise&utm_source=linkwise&utm_medium=lw&utm_campaign=lw</a>' },
  { sizes_in_stock: [ 'S', 'M' ] },
  { sizes_in_stock_feed: 'S,M,L' } ]
```

But as you can see the `additional_image_link` has an array of array that's why the output is showing `[Array]`. But I want it's should be single array link `all_sizes`.

**I have recursive function to loop through array of array :**

```
function loop(data, outputArray) {
    if(!Array.isArray(data)) { 
        outputArray.push(data);
    } else {
        data.forEach( ( element ) => {
            if(Array.isArray(element)) {
                loop(element, outputArray);
            } else {
                outputArray.push(element);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But no idea how to use it to the function.

May be I need to work on this block:

```
if( Array.isArray( obj[ property ] ) ) {
    additional.push({
        [property] : obj[property]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if object property contains an array or not and then by using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) you can convert the multi dimensional array into single dimensional.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let obj = {
  "additional_image_link": [
    [
      "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@2.jpg",
      "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@2F.jpg",
    ]
  ],
  "aff_link": "https://go.linkwi.se/z/11593-0/CD24352/?lnkurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.celestino.gr%2Fel-GR%2Fpanteloni-me-pietes-lefko%2Fprd%2FSK7732.1825%2F7%3Faffiliate%3Dlinkwise%26utm_source%3Dlinkwise%26utm_medium%3Dlw%26utm_campaign%3Dlw",
  "all_sizes": [
    "S",
    "M",
    "L"
  ],
  "availability": "Y",
  "brand": "Celestino",
  "breadcrumbs": [
    "ΡΟΥΧΑ",
    "ΠΑΝΤΕΛΟΝΙΑ"
  ],
  "breadcrumbs_url": [
    "/el-gr/gynaikeia-rouxa/r=0000000006",
    "/el-gr/gynaikeia-pantelonia/r=0101000000",
    "/el-gr/pantelonia/r=0101001800"
  ],
  "description": "Παντελόνι με πιέτες, κλείσιμο με φερμουάρ και κουμπί, θηλιές στη μέση, με τσέπες, λευκο",
  "id": "SK7732.1825+1",
  "image_link": "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@1F.JPG",
  "link": "https://www.celestino.gr/el-GR/panteloni-me-pietes-lefko/prd/SK7732.1825/7?affiliate=linkwise&utm_source=linkwise&utm_medium=lw&utm_campaign=lw",
  "sizes_in_stock": [
    "S",
    "M"
  ],
  "sizes_in_stock_feed": "S,M,L",
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if(Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    obj[key] = obj[key].flat();
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.concat` with spread operator to achieve this. However, this will work only 1 level. If you have a deeply nested object, You will have to create a recursive method.

```
[property] : [].concat(...obj[property])
```

**Sample:**

```js
let obj = {
  "additional_image_link": [
    [
      "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@2.jpg",
      "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@2F.jpg",
    ]
  ],
  "aff_link": "https://go.linkwi.se/z/11593-0/CD24352/?lnkurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.celestino.gr%2Fel-GR%2Fpanteloni-me-pietes-lefko%2Fprd%2FSK7732.1825%2F7%3Faffiliate%3Dlinkwise%26utm_source%3Dlinkwise%26utm_medium%3Dlw%26utm_campaign%3Dlw",
  "all_sizes": [
    "S",
    "M",
    "L"
  ],
  "availability": "Y",
  "brand": "Celestino",
  "breadcrumbs": [
    "ΡΟΥΧΑ",
    "ΠΑΝΤΕΛΟΝΙΑ"
  ],
  "breadcrumbs_url": [
    "/el-gr/gynaikeia-rouxa/r=0000000006",
    "/el-gr/gynaikeia-pantelonia/r=0101000000",
    "/el-gr/pantelonia/r=0101001800"
  ],
  "description": "Παντελόνι με πιέτες, κλείσιμο με φερμουάρ και κουμπί, θηλιές στη μέση, με τσέπες, λευκο",
  "id": "SK7732.1825+1",
  "image_link": "https://2ccdn.celestino.gr/small/SK7732.1825-7@1F.JPG",
  "link": "https://www.celestino.gr/el-GR/panteloni-me-pietes-lefko/prd/SK7732.1825/7?affiliate=linkwise&utm_source=linkwise&utm_medium=lw&utm_campaign=lw",
  "sizes_in_stock": [
    "S",
    "M"
  ],
  "sizes_in_stock_feed": "S,M,L",
};

let additional = [];
const isValidUrl = () => true
        
for( property in obj ) {
    if( Array.isArray( obj[ property ] ) ) {
        additional.push({
            [property] : [].concat(...obj[property])
        });
    } else if ( isValidUrl ( obj[ property ] ) ) {
         additional.push({
            [property] : '<a href="' + obj[ property ] + '">' + obj[ property ] + '</a>'
        });
    } else {
         additional.push({
            [property] : obj[property]
        });
    }
}

console.log( additional )
```

Comment: Than you so much. Yes, I might have deeply nested object. What should I do then? Can you show me?

Comment: Can you update question with possible structure?

Comment: it could be just array of array OR object has array value.

Comment: For that, you can refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272533/flattening-deeply-nested-array-of-objects)**